# Converting timestamp in a dataframe to date and time in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

[In the image I have a dataframe.In that I have a column called **timestamp** ,from that I want to **seperate month** and have to make it as a **new column**.How to do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMWUs.png)

Comment: Please include your example DF in a code block - not as an image... Also... what type is `timestamp` - is it a string or is it already a datetime-like obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Timestamp` is not already `datetime` than convert like so:

```
df["Timestamp_converted"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

You get the month as a separate column with this:

```
df["month"] = df.Timestamp_converted.dt.month
```